# How to Insert dynamic script in Angular based on environment variable in Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, environment-variables, stripe-payments

I have a script at the bottom of the index.html file within an Angular app that I want to change based on an environment variable in Node. I want to use one public api key with staging and another with production.

I use the same grunt build for both staging and production, so I don't know if dynamically changing the constants on build as suggested [here](http://mindthecode.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-your-angular-application/) is the best solution.

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

When environment variable is NODE_ENV=production, insert this:

```
 <script>
 Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_live_NN4j94VX3mtz2wJtIO3bmH');
 </script>
```

When environment variable is NODE_ENV=staging, insert this:

```
<script>
 Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_LgtEvbZwjC2GaKQYE3I6NnzuA');
</script>
```

Comment: Dynamically changing constants at build time is really the only good way to do it, I'm not sure how else you'd handle it. SOMEWHERE you need to read in or toggle an environment variable, and if that variable happens to be part of your build control, that's an ok place to put it. If you want a less angular solution so you can just include a global config js script before your angular build.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be a bad idea to create a configuration module. (Basically a JSON object that is exported) so that you can use the variables  based on a environmental variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`grunt-ng-constant`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ng-constant) to manage your angular environment variables and then initialize Stripe inside of your angular `app.config()` function rather than your document.

My preference is to manage Stripe inside the angular boot process using [`angular-stripe`](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe). This also may make your life easier if you configure your application with both keys. Here's some example code from one of my applications.

```
var $app = angular.module('app', ['angular-stripe']);
$app.constant('devDomains', ['localhost', 'staging.mydomain.com']);
$app.constant('stripePubKeyStaging', 'STRIPE_PUB_KEY_HERE');
$app.constant('stripePubKey', 'STRIPE_PUB_KEY_HERE');

$app.config(function(devDomains, stripePubKey, stripePubKeyStaging, stripeProvider) {
  if (devDomains.indexOf(document.location.hostname) !== -1 || document.location.search.indexOf('stripe-test-key') !== -1) {

    // if you're running your angular app on local or staging, use the test key. Additionally 
    // if you load your page with ?stripe-test-key you can force your production app 
    // to use the test key in order to debug something on live if you'd like.
    stripeProvider.setPublishableKey(stripePubKeyStaging);
  } else {
    stripeProvider.setPublishableKey(stripePubKey);
  }
});
```